# How to reuse UICollectionViewCell with nested UIView for video

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I am using a UICollectionViewController to display cells with content loaded from an external JSON api. To be specific, these cells include UILabels for the user that posted the video, the title of the video, etc.

In addition to the text labels, there is a large UIView in the middle of the cell to play video.

The following is the code for my UICollectionViewCell.

```
class PostCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    var videoCell: VideoPlayerView

    let storyTitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let storyTitleLabel = UILabel()
        storyTitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return storyTitleLabel
    }()

    let usernameLabel: UILabel = {
        let usernameLabel = UILabel()
        usernameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return usernameLabel
    }()

    func prepare(post: ApiPost) {
        self.usernameLabel.text = post.user?.username
        self.postTitleLabel.text = post.title!
        self.storyTitleLabel.text = post.story?.title
        self.videoCell.prepare(post: post)
    }

    func focus() {
        self.videoCell.focus()
    }

    func unfocus() {
        self.videoCell.unfocus()
    }


}
```

When a user is scrolling through the UICollectionView and the middle of the screen is over the visible UICollectionViewCell, the focus method is called.

This loads up the video corresponding to the ApiPost (api data wrapper) for that UICollectionViewCell.

I have also programmed my own subclass of UIView for the videoCell as you can see. The following is the source code of that class.

```
class VideoPlayerView: UIView {

    func prepare(post: ApiPost) {
        self.post = post
        self.videoUrl = sharedConfig.apiUrl + "/stream/" + post.video!.uuid! + ".mp4"

        if let url = URL(string: self.videoUrl!) {

            let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)

            if (self.hasReceivedApiData) {
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    print("inserting...")
                    self.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: avPlayerItem)
                    print("done")
                }
            } else {
                self.hasReceivedApiData = true
                self.player = AVQueuePlayer.init()
                self.player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
                self.player?.insert(avPlayerItem, after: nil)

                self.player?.volume = 1
                let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
                playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -70, width: self.frame.width - 32, height: self.frame.height)
                self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            }
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                    self.player?.play()
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func focus() {
        self.player?.volume = 1.0
        self.player?.play()
    }

    func unfocus() {
        self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        self.player?.pause()
    }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that when I scroll over the UICollectionView, it lags really badly when prepare() is called on a reused UICollectionViewCell. It seems that calling `self.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: avPlayerItem)` is slowing the UI down on scroll. I have verified this by putting the print calls between. It seems this is a slow operation that is lagging the UI, as you can see, I even tried putting that operation on a different thread, but no luck.

Am I displaying video properly in a UICollectionViewCell? Should I be doing this using some other method? The only way I could figure out to clear the old video is by using an `AVQueuePlayer` to clear out old AVPlayerItems, and insert the new AVPlayerItem when the cell is reused and prepared for the next video.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of initializing a variable with a video clip such that you can load it into the memory?

Comment: @ElTomato Remember that the UIView is loaded within the hierarchy of UICollectionView, each UICollectionViewCell is reloaded when the user scrolls. This presents a problem when reusing a UICollectionViewCell which has already loaded a previous video clip. The lag comes when I make the call to add the AvPlayerItem to the queue so I can reset the UICollectionViewCell for the next video.